# ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 400, statusText: "OK", url: "https://reqres.in/api/register", ok: false, …}

Tags: angular, http, http-status-code-400

getData():Observable{
return   this.http.get(this.apiUrl + "api/users?page=2").pipe(map(res=>{
return res as any
}))
}

create(body:any):Observable{
return this.http.post(this.apiUrl +'api/register' , body , {observe:'response'}).pipe(map((response)=>{
return response as any
}))
}

Comment: createUser(f:any){
    const body={
        email:f.email,
        password:f.password,
    }

    if(body.email &&  body.password){     
        this.apiServ.create(body).subscribe((res)=>{
            if(res.status == 200 ){
                console.log('yes this is user')
                  this.router.navigate(['login'])
                  
            }else if(res.status == 400){
                  console.log('Response = 400')
            }else{
              console.log(res)
            }
        })
    }else{
      console.log('error')
    }
  }

Comment: Welcome. Try to formulate the question in words